# How do I count the number of occurrences that a value in a Power BI matrix > X

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measure that counts the number of occurrences where any employee worked in excess of 45 hours in any week. I've looked at other posted questions and can't seem to connect the dots to my specific question. The following matrix shows the total hours worked by employee by week:

- Employees and Hours (the rows and values in the matrix, respectively) reside in the same table called "Power BI Upload"
- Week Number (Columns in the matrix) reside in a separate table called "Date Table"

[image: Weekly Hours by Employee]

My desired total row would show:

- Week 30 has 2 total occurrences (50 and 48)
- Week 31 has 3 total occurrences (60, 54, 47)
- Week 32 has 3 total occurrences (48, 47, 47)
- Week 33 has 5 total occurrences (46, 47, 72, 64, 68)
- Week 34 has 5 total occurrences (48, 55, 56, 67, 62)

I hope I am being clear. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a DAX measure to Power BI Upload to count those employees with greater than 45 hours in a week as follows;

```
Over45 = CALCULATE(COUNT('Power BI Upload'[Employee Name]),FILTER('Power BI Upload',[Hours]>45))
```

That'll allow you to take your matrix data of

[image: Hours Worked Matrix]

and turn it into

[image: Measure result over 45]

Comment: Thank you, @Daryl. 
Unfortunately, that did not work because the measure is trying to calculate the number of hours worked in a single day - a day being the base calculation of hours. 

I tested this with lower thresholds, "hours>5" and it returns count of days where the employee worked more than 5 hours that week. So using the 45 hour mark, it looks for hours exceeding 45 in any single day, and obviously returns blank. 

My weekly hours is really the summation of 7 potential days of work. Any idea what I can add to this measure to have it group by week?